# playframework play pac4j - how do i install?

Tags: playframework

i'm trying to install pac4j using that sbt file. Irritatingly - really - the documentation doesn't just *tell* me what line to use to install it, instead preferring clues.

I just want a line that looks like this:

```
"org.pac4j" %% "play-pac4j" % "2.6.2",
```

But that won't resolve. Can anyone give me such a line?

Comment: Try a single `%` (`"org.pac4j" % "play-pac4j" % "2.6.2"`). A double `%` adds the Scala version to your artifact, which you don't want in this case since it's not a Scala library.

Comment: oh my goodness, thankyou so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs says](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j#1-add-the-required-dependencies-play-pac4j--pac4j--libraries), all the artifacts are available in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cpac4j). If you go there and you will see `play-pac4j` version `2.6.2`. Then, when navigating to [this version](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.pac4j%7Cplay-pac4j%7C2.6.2%7Cjar), there is the exact code you should add for sbt (and other tools):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.pac4j" % "play-pac4j" % "2.6.2"
```

Comment: if you can, please update your answer to explicitly note that i messed up the number of % signs in my original attempt?